# Functional tests not recognising any routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, functional-testing

I'm trying to write a very basic functional test for one of my controllers, but the problem is that it's not recognising any of my routes. They all work in the app via HTTP and can be seen in rake routes.

In fact I even added

```
puts ActionController::Routing::Routes.inspect
```

and it put out all my routes before the error.

Here's the test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get signup" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:users)
  end
end
```

The error:

```
1) Error:
test_should_get_signup(UsersControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
/test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:5:in `test_should_get_signup'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/projectzebra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7...]

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Rake routes:

```
               POST   /users(.:format)                       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
new_user_en_gb GET    /users/new(.:format)                   {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
```

Comment: what test tool are you using? It doesn't look rspec-ish to me...this only matters because I've never used anything beyond rspec for my unit tests (functional and otherwise)

Comment: also, what's the full trace? It could be that the real error is being masked by the whole routing error thing...

Comment: it's [Test::Unit](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/), the testing framework that's part of the standard Ruby library (Ruby comes with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a functional test for the route itself, see if that passes, and go from there.

Something like:

```
test "should route to new user" do
  assert_routing '/users/new', { :controller => "users", :action => "new" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, first time working with locales in routes. That was the problem, I wasn't passing the locale and this test caught it!

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in my "journey" gem. They made routes more stricter in journey 1.0.4 which only show up on "test" environment. It is good for "developement" and "production".

** Ensure you are using exactly the same parameters as declared in routes **

Either add:

```
get :index, :locale => "en"
```

or in your Gemfile update:

```
gem 'journey', '1.0.3'
```